# Java creating .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm learning Java and I have a problem. I created 6 different classes, each has it's own `main()` method. I want to create executable `.jar` for each class, that is 6 executable `.jar` files.

So far I tried

```
java -jar cf myJar.jar myClass.class
```

and I get *'Unable to access jarfile cf'*. I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. I'm also using Eclipse IDE if that means something.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In order to create a .jar file, you need to use `jar` instead of `java`:

```
jar cf myJar.jar myClass.class
```

Additionally, if you want to make it executable, you need to indicate an *entry point* (i.e., a class with `public static void main(String[] args)`) for your application. This is usually accomplished by creating a [manifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file that contains the `Main-Class` header (e.g., `Main-Class: myClass`).

However, as Mark Peters pointed out, with JDK 6, you can use the `e` option to define the entry point:

```
jar cfe myJar.jar myClass myClass.class
```

Finally, you can execute it:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

#### See also

- [Creating a JAR File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)
- [Setting an Application's Entry Point with the JAR Tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: This is missing the point isn't it?  Are `cf` even valid options to `java`?  Either way, he wants to create the jar, not run it.  According to the question anyway.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Typo, I meant jar. Thanks.

Comment: In which case you don't need the `-jar` argument do you?  Plus, this won't make it executable since you don't specify a manifest.  (Apparently in JDK 6+ you can use "e" as a shortcut to avoid supplying the manifest manually: `jar cfe myJar.jar myClass myClass.class`)

Comment: I always get "no main manifest attribute, in myJar.jar" when I try to run it :/

Comment: If you want executable jar, you'd need to add the manifest file, something like `jar -cvfm out.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF src/*.class`

Comment: What does `cf` mean here?

Comment: @KayvanShah means, create file

Answer (score 18):

Sine you've mentioned you're using Eclipse... Eclipse can create the JARs for you, so long as you've run each class that has a main once.  Right-click the project and click Export, then select "Runnable JAR file" under the Java folder.  Select the class name in the launch configuration, choose a place to save the jar, and make a decision how to handle libraries if necessary.  Click finish, wipe hands on pants.

Answer (score 10):

Often you need to put more into the manifest than what you get with the `-e` switch, and in that case, the syntax is:

```
jar -cvfm myJar.jar myManifest.txt myApp.class
```

Which reads: "create verbose jarFilename manifestFilename", followed by the files you want to include.

Note that the name of the manifest file you supply can be anything, as `jar` will automatically rename it and put it into the right place within the jar file.

Answer (score 6):

way 1 :

Let we have java file test.java which contains main class testa
now first we compile our java file simply as javac test.java
we create file manifest.txt in same directory and we write Main-Class: mainclassname . e.g :

```
  Main-Class: testa
```

then we create jar file by this command :

```
  jar cvfm anyname.jar manifest.txt testa.class
```

then we run jar file by this command : java -jar anyname.jar

way 2 :

Let we have one package named one and every class are inside it.
then we create jar file by this command :

```
  jar cf anyname.jar one
```

then we open manifest.txt inside directory META-INF in anyname.jar file and write

```
  Main-Class: one.mainclassname
```

in third line., then we run jar file by this command :

```
  java -jar anyname.jar
```

to make jar file having more than one class file : jar cf anyname.jar one.class two.class three.class......

Answer (score 1):

Put all the 6 classes to 6 different projects. Then create jar files of all the 6 projects. In this manner you will get 6 executable jar files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually deal with the Manifest file you can use the "e" option. This explicitly defines the entry point in your application.

```
jar vcfe anyname.jar EntryPoint EntryPoint.class <files to include>
```

In my case it looked like this

```
jar vcfe people.jar Peer Peer.class ClientThread.class transport/*
```

As a result, I was able to run my program with

```
java -jar people.jar
```