# Jmeter Junit Issue

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to execute jmeter tests in jnuit testcases. I am not able to find JmeterTestCase in jmeter lib.

In which jar JmeterTestCase.class can be found?

Answer (score 3):

Try this tutorial:

[jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the jar yourself. If you are using Eclipse, right click on the project > Export > Java > Jar > click Next > Finish. If you use another IDE you can use their export process or follow this [Java creating .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file) .
That jar needs to be placed in the lib\junit directory.
For the rest follow the tutorial given by BlackGaff. It explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

please clarify what do you mean by  . "*I am not able to find JmeterTestCase in jmeter lib.*"

I guess you want to run Jmeter test cases (jmx files) as Juint test cases

you can  either implement JavaSamplerClient or to extend AbstractSamplerClient.

this question might be of good help for you,

[How to write a JMeter test for Java Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286893/how-to-write-a-jmeter-test-for-java-request)