# Jmeter - How to post HTML data and recieve live feed without getting disconnected from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a web application that provides price feeds when user subscribes to it. Typically users stay connected to the application for more than 10 minutes, that essentially puts load on the server. So I'm using Jmeter to mimic the same scenario. After I post the price feed id then I receive the first price feed but then Junit disconnects that thread to mark it successful/complete. However I want to stay connected to get the price feeds continuously. Is there a timer or something similar I could use in Jmeter to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using a JUnit Request to accomplish this? Why not just write some kind of conditional loop that keeps listening until 10 minutes are up?

See comments here [Jmeter Junit Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147155/jmeter-junit-issue) for JUnit Request tutorial