# java 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, windows, jar

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the 'jar' command in the command line on windows  :
 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command

The general solution seems to be that I need to add the jdk bin folder to the PATH in environment variables. I have already done this, I added the following to the path variable :
...; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\;

Though I'm not sure if having the jdk reside in 'program files' instead of 'program files x86' affects this. I'm on 64 bit windows with 64 bit java.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to run an "executable" jar?

Comment: trying to create a jar of a manifest.txt file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The path should only contain directories where the OS will look for executables. Strip the trailing "\jar.exe" to set your path as:

(old path variables here);C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin

Thanks To : @stevevls

Answer (score 11):

Try using this command:

```
java -version
```

If it doesn't work that means you failed to properly add path to jdk.
If it does work, try using:

```
java -jar
```

Comment: java -version works.
java -jar returns "Error: -jar requires jar file specification"

Comment: 'java -jar' command requires you to specify the .jar file you want to run.

Answer (score 3):

The **jar** command in command line is used in order to create a JAR file. For example:

```
 jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

See more at: [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

If you want to run the existed JAR file you should use the **java -jar** command mentioned by @Aleksandr.

But in your case it looks like you don't have an access to the added directory in your path with JKD binaries so at the beginning try to execute mentioned **java --version** to check whether you have java in you classpath at all.

**Please remember that on Windows you have to restart the console when you change the windows default path. You do not see the changes on the current console.**

The x64 version of Java is installed on *Program Files*. The x86 version is installed on *Program Files x86* by default.

Comment: I can run java -version and java -jar. Can you clarify how simply running 'jar...' vs 'java -jar...' differ ( and what causes one to fail when the other doesn't?). Is it an issue with the classpath?

Thanks

Comment: The "java -jar" command is used to run JAR-Packaged software. The JAR file needs to contain the Main class. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file. The "jar" command is used to package the software to JAR file. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file

Answer (score 2):

Five steps to solve this problem:

1. check whether in your `bin` folder jar.exe is availbale or not
2. check for your environmental setting
3. download jar file from here http://originaldll.com/file/jar.exe/29248.html and keep in `bin` folder
4. now check for jar it will 100% work
5. keep any jar in your desktop and go to desktop path on cmd prompt and run the command `jar xf filename.jar`

Now see if it is working