# How can I solve the error : 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: java, jar

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the '`jar`' command in the command line on windows : `'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

There is a general guess that seems to be right that is I might have the `PATH` environment variable incorrectly. But I have already done this, I added the following value to `PATH` variable : '`C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`'.

I am running a 64 bit windows 8 system.
I have also referenced this question from the following link:
[java 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180639/java-jar-is-not-recognized-as-an-[1]internal-or-external-command)

I have also tried some of the solutions suggested in the above link, I couldnt add a comment there since my reputation is not much.

Suggestions that I have tried from the above link:

[1]https://stackoverflow.com/a/29180681/7639034

(From the above link, java -version and java -jar are also working. What is wrong with the jar file then?)

[2]https://stackoverflow.com/a/42492380/7639034

Comment: `java` works but `javac` doesn't works.

Comment: See my answer, follow that. It will work

Comment: You need to add `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`  -- note the **`\bin`** section at the end -- to your PATH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Path variable should be pointing to `bin` folder, that's where executable are stored. Currently you are having path only upto `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25` so you are getting error.

Create `JAVA_HOME` environment variable which points to above location, and add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` variable. It will work.

Comment: Can you print your PATH variable?

Comment: `PATH` variable : C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk 1.8.0_25\bin

Comment: And have you closed and re-opened your command prompt after modification to PATH variable?

Comment: Do you have jar.exe inside folder?

Comment: yeah, from that suggestion I downloaded jar.exe and then placed it in the bin folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142155/discussion-between-code-ninja-and-veera-kannadiga).

Answer (score -2):

try

```
java -jar [YOURJAR]
```

this should work to execute jars

Comment: I want to create an 'executable jar' from the 'manifest.mf' file. For that i need to execute `jar` command but its not working.