# How do I Make this code run in CMD when i click the jar file

Tags: java, runtime

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        do {
            count = count + 1;

            if (count == 500000000) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.print(count);
            System.out.print("\n");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }while(true);
    }
}
```

Simply want this to run in the console from jar file, not in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a text file named Main.mf which contains following two lines:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: Main

2)Then create the archive by typing:

```
     jar cmf Main.mf Main.jar Main.class Main.java
```

3) Then run it by using

```
     java -jar Main.jar
```

Comment: Class name is `com.company.Main`

Comment: Jar is not a command it says

Comment: @NathanJohnson please make sure path variable is added. If you are not familiar with that follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180639/java-jar-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command