# Extracting a jar of .m2 folder

Tags: java, jar, war

I have to extract a war file.

the command is "jar -xvf CameraSimulator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war", but when I fire the command terminal it says 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

If i try to use "java jar CameraSimulator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" it doesn't work.
Please help me out. I am stuck
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180639/java-jar-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: do you have jdk installed?The jar command is present there

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a JDK installed. Either way it's just a plain old zip archive with another file extension. So on Linux just use unzip or on Windows just rename the file to .zip and the explorer will be able to extract it for you.