# Double click won't start executable jar

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I ran into a strange issue.When double click an executable jar it won't open
however if I do the following it starts without a problem:

```
java -jar working_neon.jar
```

This jar is a swing gui application.The jar file creation is done by eclipse
Here is the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ miglayout15-swing.jar Message.jar org.apache.commo
 ns.io.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: gui.FileCopyManager
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It wont open because ... (what is happening?)

Comment: seriously @Antoniossss ?Thanks for your helpful answer

Comment: @JohnKananakis He's telling you that you need to describe your problem. Saying "it won't open" isn't a very good description. What *exactly* happens?

Comment: could  you please post maifest file?

Comment: Is your Java program a GUI application? If it only prints stuff to the console, then I don't think you can run it by double click. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: can you give me an example of javaw

Comment: did you write your own main class?

Comment: I think the Main-Class should be gui.FileCopyManager

Comment: the problem is that i create this file using eclipse jar creator

Comment: @JohnKananakis yeah seriously, and this was comment not answer....

Comment: try to create jar manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file

Comment: @JohnKananakis see here for [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just because you double click on it, it doesn't mean that you operating system knows what to do with a jar file. So, google how to setup your OS to understand that.

Comment: I’m suspicious of `Class-Path: .`.  That means your program looks for libraries (not including .jar files, I’m pretty sure) in the current directory, and the current directory can easily be different when double-clicking than it is when you run in a cmd window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix my problem by selecting `Extract required libraries into generated jar` when creating a jar file from eclipse

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse: Go to File->Export, under Java folder select 'Runnable JAR file', under Launch configuration select the class where your main method is. Select the export destination, then select Library handling to 'Package required libraries into generated JAR', and click on finish. This works for my swing gui app. I hope it helps

Comment: i am doing  the same thing with no luck.strange thing this method works for some other applications

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you **don't use a higher Java-version in Eclipse Project-settings / Run-Configuration than** the **JRE used to run the jar**.

In Eclipse right-click you project -> Properties -> Java-Build-Path -> Libraries.

There you will see the JRE-Version that will be required to run the jar. (Also check the JRE-Version set in Run-Configuration)

Open commandline and type

```
java -version
```

Make sure the version displayed there is at least as high, as the one you found in Build-Path and Run-Configuration!

If the version displayed is not as high as the version in build-path either decrease the JRE-version set in Eclipse Build-Path/Run-Configuration or - if not possible - change your PATH-variable to use a higher versioned JRE.