# how to create jar file from source code

Tags: java, jar

I am beginner in java programming. I have source code of jacorb and need to change a .java file and recreate jacorb.jar. I change java file but how to create jar file? Please guide me in details

Comment: You are probably using an IDE like Eclipse. Most IDEs have an "export to Jar" command. Otherwise you have to use the `jar` command line tool.

Comment: This is basic and there is many information about this topic in Internet.

Comment: Like the first hit in google: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java creating .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you're working.. In Eclipse, use the Export - Java - JAR file option. For commandline it's the jar command you want.

Comment: I open it as project in eclipse but when select export as jar there is nothing to select