# How to package a library in to a .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, packaging

I want to put jar into my generated jar file .
i want to include a new dependency (external.jar) for my executable jar file.the external.jar do not contain a main method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java creating .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file)

Comment: my external.jar don't have a main method

Answer (score 0):

Use `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)`. I recommend reading http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html and [Java creating .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file)

Comment: i want to include new depandancy for a generated jar file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mavan, you can add the next to pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: i want to add a dependency without maven , without access to the source code .