# Deploy Angular-CLI as zip archive

Tags: webpack, zip, angular-cli

How to modify/extend a new Angular CLI 1.6 (and later) project so after running `ng build --prod` we also generate a ZIP archive of the production website?

I want it to be an integral part of the CLI build process, if possible, and not a custom external solution (which I'm currently using).

Comment: You can add a command to `package.json` called `postbuild`, and npm will run it automatically after `build` - but that is so well known that you must have something else in mind. Would you please add a note as to why not postbuild, and why?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using java cmd and it working:

let run:

```
jar -cMf target.zip dist
```

or:

```
jar -cMf target.zip *
```

read more in here: [Java creating .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file)

Comment: I'm looking for an integral to the Angular CLI build solution, not an external one.

Comment: ah ok, did you solved thí error