# Failure to create jar through cmd but no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having trouble creating a .jar file from my code in the CMD. While i could do much research and troubleshoot I figured I would try exporting a .jar file from eclipse. It worked perfectly but i don't know what eclipse is running behind the scenes. Is there anyway to show what it is doing so I can learn what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java creating .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file)

Comment: Yes, Amadeusz has pointed you to the jar command. Take a look at the link.

Comment: thank you for this link, but i think you misunderstand my question. i do not want to know how to make a jar file, but rather how to view the commands eclipse is running.