# How to run the appium automated project to cloud for n no. of users

Tags: automation, appium, devops

I need to upload my automated project to cloud and run the suite n no. of time and also it can be access by let say 10 people and they can also run parallel. Like n no. of people access Amazon or other website at same time.

Is it possbile?

Or

how to create jar/ some executable for appium project so that any one can use it in their laptop or desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Try Saucelab for cloud hosting and to make a jar file for your project follow  [java-creating-jar-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597866/java-creating-jar-file)

Comment: Already tried that but how can 100 people at same time can use single virtual device. Please note it is not possible to arrange one virtual device for all the end user as it costs alot.